# Finding counts of embedded entities in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate-search

I have the following 2 entity definitions. The relation from Attribute to AttributeValue is One To Many. I want to search on Attribute entities by a specified attribute category and return all 
matching attribute entities that have at least one attribute value associated with it.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried a naive approach of first searching all attribute that match specified attribute category, then for each such attribute, do a search on attribute value by attribute and return all matched entities. This way, I know for sure if an attribute has at least one one attribute value associated with it. This approach is pretty slow though.

**Question:**

Is there a better way of doing this in hibernate search? (Preferably after a search on attribute, I already have all attribute value count information returned.) I've read through the **[Embedded and associated objects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-associated)** section in the latest hibernate search official document but could not come around to have a clear approach. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Attribute {

    @Id
    @DocumentId
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String attributeName;

    @Field
    @FieldBridge(impl = EnumBridge.class)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY", nullable = false)
    private AttributeCategory attributeCategory;

    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = {"id"})
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "attribute", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<AttributeValue> attributeValues = new HashSet<>();  }

public class AttributeValue {

    @Id
    @DocumentId
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_NAME")
    private String attributeValueName;

    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = {"id", "attributeName"})
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ATTRIBUTE_ID")
    private Attribute attribute;  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all `AttributeValue` have an id, you could try something like this:

```java
AttributeCategory expectedCategory = ...;
QueryBuilder qb = ...;
Query luceneQuery = qb.bool()
    .must( qb.keyword().onField( "attributeCategory" )
            .matching( expectedCategory ).createQuery() )
    .must( qb.keyword().wildcard().onField( "attributeValues.id" )
            .matching( "*" ).createQuery() )
    .createQuery();
FullTextQuery query = Search.getSearchEntityManager( entityManager )
        .createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, Attribute.class );
query.setMaxResults( 20 );
List<Attribute> hits = query.getResultList();
```

It's a bit more intuitive (and probably more efficient) in Hibernate Search 6 (in Beta), with the [`exists` predicate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-exists). But that would require that you change most of your code, since APIs are different:

```java
AttributeCategory expectedCategory = ...;
List<Attribute> hits = Search.session( entityManager )
        .search( Attribute.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool()
            .must( f.match().field( "attributeCategory" )
                .matching( expectedCategory ) )
            .must( f.exists().field( "attributeValue" ) ) )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

Comment: Switching to Hibernate Search 6 is not option for now. What is the purpose of this line of code : List<Attribute> hits = query.list();  ?

Comment: @Lyn I fixed it; it should have been `getResultList()` instead of `list()`, since we're using JPA here and not the native Hibernate ORM API (`Session`). The purpose was just to retrieve the search hits, i.e. the "results".